# does ArrayList.removeAll(Collection<>) cares about duplicates?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, removeall

Lets say I define a list:

```
List<String> cards = new ArrayList<>();
cards.add("king");
cards.add("queen");
cards.add("king");
cards.add("king");
cards.add("prince");
cards.add("queen");
cards.add("prince");
```

So this ArrayList has 3 "king" String objects, 2 "queen", and 2 "prince".
So far so good.

Now I want to define a new list:

```
List<String> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();
toRemove.add("king");
toRemove.add("king");
toRemove.add("queen");
toRemove.add("queen");
toRemove.add("prince");
```

So this ArrayList has 2 "king", 2 "queen", and 1 "prince".
Now, if I will do:

```
cards.removeAll(toRemove);
```

Will this take duplicate objects into account?

If you subtract the toRemove list from the cards list, you should be left with 1 "king", 0 "queen", and 1 "prince". Right?

But will the removeAll function recognize there are duplicate objects there, and not try to remove all occurrences of "king", "queen", and "prince" from cards, so I will be left with an empty list(cards)?

will the final list be {"king", "prince"} or an empty list {} ?

Comment: Why not actually try that and see?

Comment: The method is named `removeAll`, not `subtract`. It’s also accepting an arbitrary `Collection`, not requiring a `List`, so it can’t be a “list minus list” operation. In fact, using `list.removeAll(singleton(x))` instead of `list.remove(x)` is the well-known trick to remove all occurrences of `x` instead of just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> **removeAll(Collection c)**
>
> Removes all of this collection's elements that are also contained in
>   the specified collection (optional operation). After this call
>   returns, this collection will contain no elements in common with the
>   specified collection.

Comment: so, the removeAll() method removes duplicates as well... thanks